# c++ exception : throwing std::exception

Tags: c++, exception, std

I need to throw std::exeption if rad is negetive number, how can I throw?

```
void Circle::setRad(double rad) {
    if (rad < 0)
    {
        throw(std::exception );
    }
    radius = rad;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you should throw one of the derived classes:

```
throw std::invalid_argument("radius must be nonnegative");
```